# Unable to convert bytes into dict in python

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, byte

How can i convert this json data which is bytes to a dict in python please.

[{"Value":-20,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AHU1 Room Temp2"},{"Value":"Normal","WatchName":"A: AHU1 Fan Mismatch"},{"Value":"Trading","WatchName":"Occupany Mode"},{"Value":"Close","WatchName":"Roller Door Input"},{"Value":"Disarmed","WatchName":"Security Input"},{"Value":-20,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AHU1 Room Temp1"},{"Value":"On","WatchName":"AHU1 Fan Status"},{"Value":"On","WatchName":"AHU1 Enable"}]

Comment: What have you tried and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Only a JSON 'object' becomes a Python dictionary.
A JSON array of objects becomes a list, like so:

```py
import json
json_data = '[{"Value":-20,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AHU1 Room Temp2"},{"Value":"Normal","WatchName":"A: AHU1 Fan Mismatch"},{"Value":"Trading","WatchName":"Occupany Mode"},{"Value":"Close","WatchName":"Roller Door Input"},{"Value":"Disarmed","WatchName":"Security Input"},{"Value":-20,"Unit":"°C","WatchName":"AHU1 Room Temp1"},{"Value":"On","WatchName":"AHU1 Fan Status"},{"Value":"On","WatchName":"AHU1 Enable"}]'
result = json.loads(json_data)
```